# how to add a url to tab in tab panel in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I need a tab of my tab panel to go to a url. How can I do so? I mean I want my tap on that tab to go to a url(here the url is of a pdf).

Kindly check this link    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzddXRxUeN1jOE9tTVBmSGpHQzg/edit?usp=sharing  to see the effect required

Comment: I am sorry if I am not clear but I have no codes to show. Kindly check this link    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzddXRxUeN1jOE9tTVBmSGpHQzg/edit?usp=sharing      to see the effect required

Comment: Unfortunately, this site isn't write my code, so you're gonna have to try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple.. you just have to create a iframe into the html part of that panel... hope you got it,.... something like this

```
items:[{
    xtype: 'panel',
    styleHtmlContent : true,
    html: '<div><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://www.sencha.com/products/touch">Your device does not support iframes.</iframe></div>',
}]
```

Comment: How may I open it in another tab?

Comment: dynamically create a panel and add it into item